# Split string not working properly in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, split

My table is:

```
file_content
MSH|^~\&|LCS|LCA|LIS|TEST9999|199807311532||ORU^R01|3630|P|2.2
PID|3|2161348473|OBRIEN|01572633|20923085580^TESTPAT||19730204|
OBR|1|8642753100013^LIS|20923085580^LCS|083824^PANEL 083824^L|||19980728083600|||||| CH13380|19980728000000||||||20923085580||19980730041800|||F
OBX|1|NM|150001^HIV-1 ABS-O.D. RATIO^L|||||||N|X
OBX|2|CE|001719^HIV-1 ABS, SEMI-QN^L||HTN|||||N|F|19910123|| 19980729155700|BN
OBR|2|8642753100013^LIS|20923085580^LCS|083824^PANEL 083824^L|||19980728083600|||||| CH13380|19980728000000||||||20923085580||19980730041800|||F
OBX|1|NM|150001^HIV-1 ABS-O.D. RATIO^L|||||||N|X
OBX|2|CE|001719^HIV-1 ABS, SEMI-QN^L||HTN|||||N|F|19910123|| 19980729155700|BN
```

I have the following SQL query which does not work for the above case:

```
SELECT c.COLUMN_VALUE AS obr_seq, REGEXP_SUBSTR( t.file_content, '^MSH.*?' || CHR(10) || 'PID.*?' || CHR(10) )
         || REGEXP_SUBSTR( t.file_content, 'OBR.*?' || CHR(10) || '((OBX|NTE|FT1).*?($|' || CHR(10) || '))*', 1, c.COLUMN_VALUE ) AS split_value
FROM   test_hl7_message_split t
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       TABLE(
         CAST(
           MULTISET(
             SELECT LEVEL
             FROM   DUAL
             CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT( t.file_content, 'OBR.*?' || CHR(10) || '((OBX|NTE|FT1).*?($|' || CHR(10) || '))*' )
           ) AS SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST
         )
       ) c
       ON ( 1 = 1 );
```

It is giving me wrong output:

```
OBR_SEQ     SPLIT_VALUE
1           MSH|^~\&|LCS|LCA|LIS|TEST9999|199807311532||ORU^R01|3630|P|2.2
            PID|3|2161348473|OBRIEN|01572633|20923085580^TESTPAT||19730204|
            OBRIEN|01572633|20923085580^TESTPAT||19730204|

2           MSH|^~\&|LCS|LCA|LIS|TEST9999|199807311532||ORU^R01|3630|P|2.2
            PID|3|2161348473|OBRIEN|01572633|20923085580^TESTPAT||19730204|
            OBR|1|8642753100013^LIS|20923085580^LCS|083824^PANEL 083824^L|||19980728083600|||||| CH13380|19980728000000||||||20923085580||19980730041800|||F
            OBX|1|NM|150001^HIV-1 ABS-O.D. RATIO^L|||||||N|X
            OBX|2|CE|001719^HIV-1 ABS, SEMI-QN^L||HTN|||||N|F|19910123|| 19980729155700|BN

3           MSH|^~\&|LCS|LCA|LIS|TEST9999|199807311532||ORU^R01|3630|P|2.2
            PID|3|2161348473|OBRIEN|01572633|20923085580^TESTPAT||19730204|
            OBR|2|8642753100013^LIS|20923085580^LCS|083824^PANEL 083824^L|||19980728083600|||||| CH13380|19980728000000||||||20923085580||19980730041800|||F
            OBX|1|NM|150001^HIV-1 ABS-O.D. RATIO^L|||||||N|X
            OBX|2|CE|001719^HIV-1 ABS, SEMI-QN^L||HTN|||||N|F|19910123|| 19980729155700|BN
```

The right output should be:

```
OBR_SEQ     SPLIT_VALUE
1           MSH|^~\&|LCS|LCA|LIS|TEST9999|199807311532||ORU^R01|3630|P|2.2
            PID|3|2161348473|OBRIEN|01572633|20923085580^TESTPAT||19730204|
            OBR|1|8642753100013^LIS|20923085580^LCS|083824^PANEL 083824^L|||19980728083600|||||| CH13380|19980728000000||||||20923085580||19980730041800|||F
            OBX|1|NM|150001^HIV-1 ABS-O.D. RATIO^L|||||||N|X
            OBX|2|CE|001719^HIV-1 ABS, SEMI-QN^L||HTN|||||N|F|19910123|| 19980729155700|BN

2           MSH|^~\&|LCS|LCA|LIS|TEST9999|199807311532||ORU^R01|3630|P|2.2
            PID|3|2161348473|OBRIEN|01572633|20923085580^TESTPAT||19730204|
            OBR|2|8642753100013^LIS|20923085580^LCS|083824^PANEL 083824^L|||19980728083600|||||| CH13380|19980728000000||||||20923085580||19980730041800|||F
            OBX|1|NM|150001^HIV-1 ABS-O.D. RATIO^L|||||||N|X
            OBX|2|CE|001719^HIV-1 ABS, SEMI-QN^L||HTN|||||N|F|19910123|| 19980729155700|BN
```

Basically, my script is comparing OBR in the middle of the segment and I do not want it.

Can anyone help with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its matching `OBR` in `OBRIEN` in the header. Just pre-process the string to separate the header from the body and then you can iterate over just the body of the message:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE test_hl7_message_split ( file_content ) AS
SELECT 'MSH|^~\&|LCS|LCA|LIS|TEST9999|199807311532||ORU^R01|3630|P|2.2
PID|3|2161348473|OBRIEN|01572633|20923085580^TESTPAT||19730204|
OBR|1|8642753100013^LIS|20923085580^LCS|083824^PANEL 083824^L|||19980728083600|||||| CH13380|19980728000000||||||20923085580||19980730041800|||F
OBX|1|NM|150001^HIV-1 ABS-O.D. RATIO^L|||||||N|X
OBX|2|CE|001719^HIV-1 ABS, SEMI-QN^L||HTN|||||N|F|19910123|| 19980729155700|BN
OBR|2|8642753100013^LIS|20923085580^LCS|083824^PANEL 083824^L|||19980728083600|||||| CH13380|19980728000000||||||20923085580||19980730041800|||F
OBX|1|NM|150001^HIV-1 ABS-O.D. RATIO^L|||||||N|X
OBX|2|CE|001719^HIV-1 ABS, SEMI-QN^L||HTN|||||N|F|19910123|| 19980729155700|BN' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT c.COLUMN_VALUE AS obr_seq,
       head
         || REGEXP_SUBSTR( t.body, 'OBR.*?' || CHR(10) || '((OBX|NTE|FT1).*?($|' || CHR(10) || '))*', 1, c.COLUMN_VALUE ) AS split_value
FROM   ( SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR( file_content, '^MSH.*?' || CHR(10) || 'PID.*?' || CHR(10) ) AS head,
                REGEXP_REPLACE( file_content, '^MSH.*?' || CHR(10) || 'PID.*?' || CHR(10) ) AS body
         FROM   test_hl7_message_split ) t
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       TABLE(
         CAST(
           MULTISET(
             SELECT LEVEL
             FROM   DUAL
             CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT( t.body, 'OBR.*?' || CHR(10) || '((OBX|NTE|FT1).*?($|' || CHR(10) || '))*' )
           ) AS SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST
         )
       ) c
       ON ( 1 = 1 );
```

**Output**:

> ```
> OBR_SEQ | SPLIT_VALUE                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
> ------: | :------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>       1 | MSH|^~\&|LCS|LCA|LIS|TEST9999|199807311532||ORU^R01|3630|P|2.2<br>PID|3|2161348473|OBRIEN|01572633|20923085580^TESTPAT||19730204|<br>OBR|1|8642753100013^LIS|20923085580^LCS|083824^PANEL 083824^L|||19980728083600|||||| CH13380|19980728000000||||||20923085580||19980730041800|||F<br>OBX|1|NM|150001^HIV-1 ABS-O.D. RATIO^L|||||||N|X<br>OBX|2|CE|001719^HIV-1 ABS, SEMI-QN^L||HTN|||||N|F|19910123|| 19980729155700|BN<br>
>       2 | MSH|^~\&|LCS|LCA|LIS|TEST9999|199807311532||ORU^R01|3630|P|2.2<br>PID|3|2161348473|OBRIEN|01572633|20923085580^TESTPAT||19730204|<br>OBR|2|8642753100013^LIS|20923085580^LCS|083824^PANEL 083824^L|||19980728083600|||||| CH13380|19980728000000||||||20923085580||19980730041800|||F<br>OBX|1|NM|150001^HIV-1 ABS-O.D. RATIO^L|||||||N|X<br>OBX|2|CE|001719^HIV-1 ABS, SEMI-QN^L||HTN|||||N|F|19910123|| 19980729155700|BN
> ```

**Query 2**:

The other alternative is to use the `m` match parameter in the regular expression to treat the string as multiple lines then you can match on `^OBR` to only find `OBR` at the start of the line:

```
SELECT c.COLUMN_VALUE AS obr_seq,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( t.file_content, '^MSH.*?' || CHR(10) || 'PID.*?' || CHR(10) )
         || REGEXP_SUBSTR( t.file_content, '^OBR.*?' || CHR(10) || '((OBX|NTE|FT1).*?($|' || CHR(10) || '))*', 1, c.COLUMN_VALUE, 'm' ) AS split_value
FROM   test_hl7_message_split t
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       TABLE(
         CAST(
           MULTISET(
             SELECT LEVEL
             FROM   DUAL
             CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT( t.file_content, '^OBR.*?' || CHR(10) || '((OBX|NTE|FT1).*?($|' || CHR(10) || '))*', 1, 'm' )
           ) AS SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST
         )
       ) c
       ON ( 1 = 1 );
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=eb1cc19542f25c2dc5af5b4408d278c8)*